# Passing array to typescript rest parameter

Tags: typescript

Is there a way how to pass array of arguments into typescript rest parameter, **without** changing implementation of Foo class ?

```
    class Foo{
        constructor(...restParam : string[]){}
    }

    class Test{
        CallFoo = () => {
            // Working
            let foo = new Foo("t", "t");

            // Compilation error 
            let restParamValues = ["t", "t"];
            let foo2 = new Foo(restParamValues);
    };
```

Error: *Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the typescript spread operator:

```
let foo = new Foo(...restParamValues);
```